# #(A-B)=#A-#B if and only if B⊆A?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am stuck working on a proof of cardinality, and all i can think of for this is

|$A-B|= |A|- |B|$

$A \cup B +  |B| =|A| $

$|A| =  |A| $

I cannot figure out how i would prove this (both ways too) 
any help would be gladly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*: $A\setminus B=A\setminus (A\cap B)$. Also, $\left|A\cap B\right|\leq \left|B\right|$, in general, with equality if and only if $B\subseteq A$.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I'll post my proof answer as soon as i get it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If $\left |{A-B}\right |=\left |{A}\right |-\left |{B}\right |$, then $\left |{A-B}\right |+\left |{B}\right |=\left |{A}\right |$, how $(A-B)$ and $B$ are disjoint, then;

$$\left |{A-B}\right |+\left |{B}\right |=\left |{(A-B)\cup B}\right |=\left |{A\cup B}\right |=\left |{A}\right |+\left |{B}\right |-\left |{A\cap B}\right |=\left |{A}\right |$$

Then $\left |{A\cap B}\right |=\left |{B}\right |$,
but then $(A\cap B)=B$ and this is correct, if and only if $B\subseteq A$

Comment: If this is an Iff proof doesn't B⊆A --> |A−B|=|A|−|B| need to be proven?

Comment: Is equal if $B\subseteq A$ then $(A \cap B)=B$... then you are returned in the proof.

Comment: ...then  make the proof  the end to the beginning

Comment: Can this question be proved by arbitrary method